# Fourier transform of Fourier transform of $f \in L^1\cap L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $\mathcal F$ denote the Fourier transfrom, i.e., $\mathcal Ff=\hat f$.

Suppose $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$. By the Plancherel Theorem, $\mathcal Ff\in L^2$ and $\mathcal F \mathcal Ff \in L^2$.

My question is:

$f= \mathcal F \overline{\mathcal Ff}$ a.e. or in $L^2$?

Or at least, $\mathcal F \mathcal Ff \in L^1$?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I think you have to clarify what do you mean by a.e? Do you mean that the functions $f$ and $\mathcal{F}\overline{\mathcal{F}(f)}$, as defined by Plancherel's Theorem, are almost everywhere equal or that the Fourier transform of $\overline{\mathcal{F}(f)}$, which is not integrable, so i guess you have to take an approximating sequence, converge almost everywhere to $f$?

Comment: If it is the first case, the result is trivial since equality in $L^2$ implies equality almost everywhere.

Comment: $(\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}f)(x)=f(-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\mathcal F^*f(t)=\mathcal Ff(-t)$. Then $\mathcal F^*\mathcal Ff=f $ in $L^2$ by the Plancherel Theorem.

Hence, $\mathcal F^*\mathcal Ff=f$ a.e. and $\mathcal F^*\mathcal Ff\in L^1\cap L^2$.